# Instance of my rocket and original model both displaying in render

Tags: rendering, instances

I have a model of a ship and an instance of the ship i have disabled the original model from the view port
[image]

but when i render both models appear like in the image below
[image]

how do i only render the instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Answer (score 4):

If you mask an object from the viewport, it will relly mask it **only** from the viewport.

In order to mask it from the render, open the Filter menu in the outliner, then enable the camera icon.

[image]

This way in the outliner, you will be able to toggle the visibility of any object from the render:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable it in the render as well, disable in the viewport only hides it from viewing in the viewport.

[image]

you can use the 'Filter' in the outline panel to toggle on and off different settings and to disable the layer from rendering (the camera icon).